# Prisma effect on iOS UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, core-image

I am working on a photo app where i have to apply prisma effect on UIImage. But could not get any reference for this effect still.

For reference, you can see this app.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prisma-art-filters-photo-effects/id1122649984?mt=8

Does there have any library or reference for prisma effect ?

Comment: they are manipulating images via webserver. So their are chances they are using anyother tech.

Comment: Yes, but what is the technique and are not there any similar/related work in iOS for that ? @RahulMishra

Comment: Whatever, thank you. @ RahulMishra

Comment: They're doing clever stuff with neural networks. You could hook your app up to Google's Deep Dream and play with that. Take a look at https://github.com/google/deepdream/blob/master/dream.ipynb

Comment: if it was just simply using a filter or library, Prisma app wouldn't have made to the app store top chart, would it? all I can do is purely admiring...

Comment: Yes, you are right. So it is not easy for a single developer like me. Seems they used lots of advanced Neural Netwrok and artificial intelligence. @Chris Chen

Comment: yup, there's plenty interviews about their team of 4 in Russia

Comment: Bro, You have to do more research. try to post your answer if you have found any.

Answer (score 7):

Prisma isn't using your typical filters to manipulate images. But rather a convolutional neural network that uses pre-trained models that can take any artistic style or texture and apply it to fresh content.

More specifically, Prisma takes a content image & style image on the client side and then Uploads it to a server with a powerful GPU to do the neural network processing.... as iPhones or mobile devices don't have the onboard GPU capacity to do the neural network fast enough. It would take possibly several hours on a normal CPU to process the images using the neural network model.

You can find out all about the neural network here. Using this Johnson implementation usually takes upto 10 minutes to process using a $1000 GPU or Amazon server.

https://github.com/jcjohnson/neural-style

Note: The novel aspect of the Prisma app other than being a mobile app is it can do the image processing in under 10 seconds and are using a feed forward implementation which you can read about here.

https://github.com/jcjohnson/neural-style/issues/261

I think this is one of the main reasons they are using pre-defined styles rather than allowing the user to select any arbitrary style.

Comment: +1 thanks for the great info, i thought they were using Palette API or some other, bt turns out they are using Neural Network.. Interested topic for R&D. :)

Answer (score 1):

This effect looks a lot like the Kuwahara noise reduction filter. It's implemented in the GPUImage framework.

https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage